# Error management in nested async function calls

Tags: javascript, exception, async-await, office-js

I am developing an Excel add-in using the Office JS API. I have a taskpane which is running code similar to the following:

```js
var failA = true
var failB = true

// In reality this is Excel.run, and it injects a context 
async function run(f) { 
  f()
}

// Simulate a failing async call
async function fail(message, delay) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
    throw new Error(message)
   }, delay)
}

// Simulate a successful async call
async function success(message, delay) {
    setTimeout(delay)
}

async function doA() {
    console.log("Inside A");
  if (failA) {
    console.log("Failing A");
    await fail("Error A", 1000)
  } else {
    success("Success A")
  }
  console.log("Done A")
}

async function doB() {
    console.log("Inside B");
  if (failB) {
    console.log("Failing B");
    await fail("Error B", 1000)
  } else {
    success("Success B")
  }
  console.log("Done B")
}

async function main () {
try {
    // This is how Excel.run is called in all the Office samples
    await run(async ()=>{
    console.log("Start main");
    await doA();
    console.log("Between A and B");
    await doB();
    console.log("Finished");
  })}
catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error.message)
  }
}

// Need to await main in an async context. In reality main is run from a button
(async () => await main())()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

I would expect the error in `doA` to bubble up and interrupt further execution of `doB`. The output should then be:

```
Start main
Inside A
Failing A
ERROR: Error A
```

Instead what I get is:

```
Start main
Inside A
Failing A
Done A
Between A and B
Inside B
Failing B
Done B
Finished
```

followed by two uncaught exceptions `Error A` and `Error B`.

What am I doing wrong? Can I achieve the behavior I expect without wrapping `doA` and `doB` separately in `try...catch` blocks?

Comment: Your `fail()` and `success()` functions must return Promise instances, and resolve or reject those when the timer fires.

Comment: A `throw` in an asynchronously executed callback (like with `setTimeout`) will not affect the promise returned by the `async` function. `throw` only affects the current callstack. Despite the comment, you're not simulating a failing async call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. `fail` is not simulating a failing async call. It returns an immediately fulfilling promise. The `setTimeout` callback that will later throw an error, is irrelevant for that promise, since that callback executes from a fresh call stack. Similarly, `success` is initiating a `setTimeout` that has no relevance to the promise it returns, which again gets fulfilled immediately.
2. `run` is not linking its resolution to the fate of the promise returned by `f` and thus `run` returns a promise that fulfills while `f` is not monitored for errors. If `f` rejects, `run` will not have captured it.
3. If you configure your script to execute `success` then you need to `await` it, otherwise its delay will have no effect.

Here is a fix:

```js
var failA = true;
var failB = true;

async function run(f) { 
  // Link to the returned promise, so error handling around 
  //    run() will deal with rejections
  return f(); 
}

// Helper function
const expire = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function fail(message, delay) {
  await expire(delay);
  // throw must happen in the execution context of function fail
  throw new Error(message); 
}

async function success(message, delay) {
  // Wait for the delay to expire, otherwise it is useless
  await expire(delay); 
}

async function doA() {
  console.log("Inside A");
  if (failA) {
    console.log("Failing A");
    await fail("Error A", 1000);
  } else {
    await success("Success A"); // Must await it
  }
  console.log("Done A");
}

async function doB() {
    console.log("Inside B");
  if (failB) {
    console.log("Failing B");
    await fail("Error B", 1000);
  } else {
    await success("Success B"); // Must await it
  }
  console.log("Done B");
}

async function main () {
  try {
    await run(async ()=>{
        console.log("Start main");
        await doA();
        console.log("Between A and B");
        await doB();
        console.log("Finished");
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error.message);
  }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` does not know anything about promises. Instead use a promise based sleep for waiting.

Also you forgot to `await f()` in your `run` function, or at least return it to keep promise chain intact.

```js
var failA = true
var failB = true

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// In reality this is Excel.run, and it injects a context 
async function run(f) {
    await f()
}

// Simulate a failing async call
async function fail(message, delay) {
    await sleep(delay);
    throw new Error(message)
}

// Simulate a successful async call
async function success(message, delay) {
    await sleep(delay);
}

async function doA() {
    console.log("Inside A");
    if (failA) {
        console.log("Failing A");
        await fail("Error A", 1000)
    } else {
        success("Success A")
    }
    console.log("Done A")
}

async function doB() {
    console.log("Inside B");
    if (failB) {
        console.log("Failing B");
        await fail("Error B", 1000)
    } else {
        success("Success B")
    }
    console.log("Done B")
}

async function main() {
    try {
        // This is how Excel.run is called in all the Office samples
        await run(async () => {
            console.log("Start main");
            await doA();
            console.log("Between A and B");
            await doB();
            console.log("Finished");
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error.message)
    }
}

// Need to await main in an async context. In reality main is run from a button
(async () => await main())()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```